# Split string, copy data into multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following tables

**Table A**

```
RID | Name        |Phone       |Email        |CreatedOn
------------------------------------------------------------
1 | John Smith    | 2143556789 |t1@gmail.com |2012-09-01 09:30:00
2 | Jason K Crull | 2347896543 |t2@gmail.com |2012-08-02 10:34:00
```

**Table B**

```
CID| FirstName |LastName |Phone      |Email        |CreatedOn          |Title|Address|City|State
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11 | John      | Smith   |2143556789 |t1@gmail.com |2012-09-01 09:30:00|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL
12 | Jason     | K Crull |2347896543 |t2@gmail.com |2012-08-02 10:34:00|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL
```

**Table C**

```
RID | CID |IsAuthor|CreatedOn
-----------------------------------------
1   | 11  | 0      |2012-09-01 09:30:00
2   | 12  | 0      |2012-08-02 10:34:00
```

For every row in "Table A" need to create a row in "Table B" splitting the name into First and Last Name as shown and after creating a row, insert new row into Table C with RID from Table A, CID from Table B, IsAuthor bit Default to 0 and CreatedOn from Table A.The CID is auto incremented. Can anyone help me in achieving this. I am very new to SQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this (I left off some fields, but this should get the point across).  Main thing to see is the `substring` and `charindex` functions which are used to split the name into first name and last names:

```
insert into tableb (firstname,lastname,phone,email)
select 
  left(name, charindex(' ',name)-1), 
  substring(name, charindex(' ', name)+1, len(name)), 
  phone, email
from tablea ;

insert into tablec
select a.rid, b.cid, 0, a.createdon
from tablea a 
  inner join tableb b on a.name = b.firstname + ' ' + b.lastname
    and a.phone = b.phone and a.email = b.email ;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf108/2)

If there is a concern for the same names, emails, etc, then you're probably going to need to look into using a dreaded cursor and `scope_identity()`.  Hopefully you won't have to go down that route.

Comment: @Krishh -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

Stop thinking about "for every row" and think of it as "a set." Very rarely is it efficient to process anything row-by-row in SQL Server, and very rarely is it beneficial to think in those terms.

```
--INSERT dbo.TableC(RID, CID, IsAuthor, CreatedOn)
  SELECT a.RID, b.CID, IsAuthor = 0, a.CreatedOn
  FROM dbo.TableA AS a
  INNER JOIN dbo.TableB AS b
  ON a.Name = b.FirstName + ' ' b.LastName;
```

When you believe it is returning the right results, uncomment the `INSERT`.

Comment: Thank you, I will start thinking it as "a set" from now on. I did not know how to think logically when writing sql code. You have given me an approach on how to think while writing sql scripts

Answer (score 1):

To split the name I'd use `CharIndex` to find the position of the space, then `Substring` to break the word apart.

For keeping track of which row in TableA the data in TableB came from, I'd just stick a column onto B to record this data, then drop it when you come to inset into table C.
An alternative would be to make CID an identity column on C instead of B, populate C first, then feed that data into TableB when you come to populate that.

```
if OBJECT_ID('TableA','U') is not null drop table TableA
create table TableA 
(
    rid int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
    , Name nvarchar(64)
    , Phone nvarchar(16)
    , Email nvarchar(256)
    , CreatedOn datetime default (getutcdate())
)
if OBJECT_ID('TableB','U') is not null drop table TableB
create table TableB  
(
    cid int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
    , FirstName nvarchar(64)
    , LastName nvarchar(64)
    , Phone nvarchar(16)
    , Email nvarchar(256)
    , CreatedOn datetime default (getutcdate())
    , Title nvarchar(16)
    , [Address] nvarchar(256)
    , City nvarchar(64)
    , [State] nvarchar(64)
)
if OBJECT_ID('TableC','U') is not null drop table TableC
create table TableC 
(
    rid int primary key clustered
    , cid int unique 
    , IsAuthor bit default(0)
    , CreatedOn datetime default (getutcdate())
)

insert TableA (Name, Phone, Email) select 'John Smith', '2143556789', 't1@gmail.com'
insert TableA (Name, Phone, Email) select 'Jason K Crull', '2347896543', 't2@gmail.com'

alter table TableB 
add TempRid int

insert TableB(FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email, TempRid)
select case when CHARINDEX(' ', Name) > 0 then SUBSTRING(Name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Name)-1) else Name end
, case when CHARINDEX(' ', Name) > 0 then SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Name)+1, LEN(Name)) else '' end
, Phone
, Email
, Rid
from TableA

insert TableC (rid, cid)
select TempRid, cid 
from TableB

alter table TableB
drop column TempRid

select * from TableB
select * from TableC
```

Try it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aaaed/1

Or the alternate method (inserting to C before B) here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99592/1

Comment: Thank you. Thank you for your time in explaining in detail.